# SVN Jenkins Poll Issue

Tags: jenkins

We have SVN repository in separate server and Jenkins running in separate server. Suddenly there occurs a issue like Jenkins is frequently polling builds and builds are executing concurrently and this make the server down.
We have configured Jenkins to check SVN for changes every minute(* * * * *) and the same was working fine previously

Comment: I got the below error log in Jenkins log file: Feb 26, 2016 7:08:43 PM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 52ABEE6EC4155758

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS, the problem is in jmDNS library. As a workaround, you can start Jenkins like this:

```
java -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -jar jenkins.war
```

Comment: I am running Jenkins on Centos